# MySQL Is doing subquery after LIMIT syntax possible? If not, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, subquery, limit

I have MySQL Server version 5.1.53. I was looking for an hour to answer this question by myself. Including read the documentation itself at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Currently, I run this query.

```
SELECT dv2.timestamp 
FROM data_val AS dv2
WHERE dv2.timestamp > '2011-06-10 22:26:25' ORDER BY dv3.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Then I was trying to eliminate the `ORDER BY` syntax by determining the calculation of MAX_QUERIES minus 1. By doing that I could write,

```
SELECT  (COUNT(*)-1) total 
FROM data_val AS dv2a
WHERE dv2a.timestamp > '2011-06-10 22:26:13'
```

Finally the query becomes,

```
SELECT dv2.timestamp 
FROM data_val AS dv2
WHERE dv2.timestamp > '2011-06-10 22:26:13' 
LIMIT (
     SELECT  (COUNT(*)-1) total 
     FROM data_val AS dv2a
     WHERE dv2a.timestamp > '2011-06-10 22:26:13'
     ), 1
```

And the error is:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT (COUNT(*)-1) total FROM data_val AS dv2a ' at line 4`

I also tried to put the subquery after `OFFSET` syntax. but still error.

Do you have any idea why my sub-query doesn't work?

> I need technical details with **short**,
>   **simple**, and **clean** explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be **nonnegative integer constants**, with these exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.

The MySQL query optimizer needs to resolve the limit parameters to a constant **before** running the query, or it will not know how many rows to return.

Comment: In short, MySQL does not execute my sub query first?

Comment: @exodream, Exactly, it will refuse to do so. Because that how it's programmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't imbed a query result for a limit parameter

Comment: why? I need technical details.