# MySQL - Limit with sub query

Tags: mysql

I want to limit selected all except 1st row.
**Id is int, but not UNIQUE,

checkIn is date**

```
SELECT * FROM table  
Order by property_id, checkIn DESC 
LIMIT 2, (SELECT Count(property_id)-1 FROM table)
```

Both Queries are working. but then I put them together i get

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT Count(property_id) FROM table)' at line 1`

Maybe here is universal key for all rows  at `LIMIT 1, ALL` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need all rows except the first one, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;
```

`18446744073709551615` is the recommend as a value as in the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) and the maximum of a unsigned bigint.

[There was a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255517/2321643).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's how you can do it with a prepared statement:

```
SET @skip=1; 
SET @numrows=(SELECT Count(property_id)-1 FROM table);
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM table Order by property_id, checkIn DESC LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

Although, if it's a InnoDB table, I wouldn't recommend to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on it repeatedly. Unlike MyISAM it doesn't store a row count in the table. Therefore `count`ing on InnoDB can be slow when it has lots of rows.

P.S.: Note, that you have to use `limit 1, how_many` instead of `limit 2, how_many` when you want to skip one row, since it starts counting from 0, not from 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Johan** already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312638/mysql-is-doing-subquery-after-limit-syntax-possible-if-not-why)

> You can not use a subquery as a `LIMIT` argument. Limit argument
>   should be an `INTEGER`. You subquery returns, wel... basically, a
>   table.

[From the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be **nonnegative integer constants**, with these exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.

**Edit**

Try like this

but i'm not tested

```
DECLARE offset bigint;
SELECT Count(property_id)-1 INTO offset FROM table;
SELECT * FROM table Order by property_id, checkIn DESC LIMIT 2,offset;
```

Comment: So here is no way to achieve that? I mean display all items except first one, if count of rows, is changing all the time? 
Edit: I mean by using only MySQL in one query.

Comment: It give me syntax error just at start for DECLARE'ing offset

Comment: @Laimonas Can you check now

Comment: I tryed that after i get error at first. kinda same  error
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE offset bigint' at line 1 `

Comment: @Laimonas you should not count before the values if you just need all but not the first rows. My solution is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@omeinusch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955093), but also offer the following alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM table t JOIN (
  SELECT   property_id, checkIn
  FROM     table
  ORDER BY property_id, checkIn DESC
  LIMIT    2,1
) s ON (t.property_id > s.property_id)
    OR (t.property_id = s.property_id AND t.checkIn <= s.checkIn)
```

Comment: I get  `#1054 - Unknown column 't.property_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: oh i needet to change 1st line to `SELECT * FROM table AS t JOIN (`

Comment: If i get right, it shows items which ID's is bigger than first one, though, problem in my case Id's is not unique

Comment: @Laimonas: That interpretation omits the last line, `OR ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique id column, then you could do this:

```
select * FROM table 
where id <> (SELECT id FROM table Order by property_id, checkIn DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Otherwise, assuming property_id and checkIn are unique,

```
select * FROM table 
where concat(property_id,'|',checkIn) <> 
     (SELECT concat(property_id,'|',checkIn)  FROM table Order by property_id, checkIn DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Id is not unique at this case so it wont work like that.